# graphical.target for specified users only

Tags: systemd, gui, nixos

The situation is like this:

> I am using a Linux machine as a server, accurately a NixOS (with home-manager) on Raspberry Pi 4.
>
> Therefore I don't need a GUI always ready and eating the resources.
>
> However I want to still keep the ability to spin up a GUI when I need it.

So I want to setup a user account, which upon login (in text mode) starts the X server and and something like XFCE or i3 automatically.

Is it possible through some wiggling in `systemd`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Dose `startx` work from the console for you?

Comment: @Bib The major concern is that I don't want to type `startx` every time, and I want the user be logged out when the X session is ended

Comment: Then put it into the users .profile with a `logout` afterwards, or create a script which handles it.

Comment: @Bib Can all of these be done in some kind of systemd unit? I think it may be what I am seeking for, so it would be great if you could make your suggestion an answer

Answer (score 1):

Create a script to be launched from a users `.profile` or modify it such that it calls `startx;logout`. Creating a systemd unit is liable to be backgrounded, such that it cannot stall while the X server is up and running.